# HK2 + Jersey 2.24 + JPA/Hibernate 5.2.4.Final EntityManager Inject on Tomcat- There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl

Tags: tomcat, jpa, cdi, jersey-2.0, hk2

I'm trying to implement dependency injection in EntityManager, but the following error occurs:

```
ADVERTÊNCIA: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 3
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=EntityManager,parent=TesteRepository,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,29212229)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:75)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:234)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:70)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2020)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:693)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:234)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:70)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2020)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:680)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:234)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2020)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:766)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:705)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="mydb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

  <properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
  </properties>
```

Rest Class:

```
@Path("teste")
public class Teste {

    @Inject
    private TesteService service;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<String> helloWorld() {

        return service.listaTeste();

    }

}
```

Service Class:

```
@Named
@Stateless
public class TesteService {

    @Inject
    private TesteRepository repository;

    public List<String> listarTeste(){
        return repository.listar();
    }

}
```

DAO Class:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class TesteRepository {


    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public String teste(){
        return "Teste";
    }

    public List<String> listar(){
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }

}
```

Some classes needed for injection that I got in my searches on the internet:

1. Jersey Resource Configuration for application path, scann packages and binds

   ```
   @ApplicationPath("servicos/rest")
   public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

       public MyApplication() {

           register(new MyApplicationBinder());

           packages("br.com.comprafacil.exemplo");
       }

   }
   ```
2. Bind Class: (For class dependency injection I just found this way of managing)

   ```
   public class MyApplicationBinder extends AbstractBinder {

       @Override
       protected void configure() {

           bind(TesteService.class).to(TesteService.class);
           bind(TesteRepository.class).to(TesteRepository.class);
       }

   }
   ```
3. Trying use @Produces and @PresistenceContext to create a EntityManager instance when I inject it

   ```
   public class EntityManagerProduces {

       @Produces
       @PersistenceContext(unitName = "mydb")
       private EntityManager entityManager;

   }
   ```

   - beans.xml created on webapp/WEB-INF folder
   - persistence.xml created on src/META-INF folder

I tried bind EntityManager in MyApplicationBinder class, but I was not successful.

I'm newbie with Jersey + CDI + JPA. 
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Is not this the best way to do injection in EntityManager? What is the best way to do this?